java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/foundation/text2/input/TextFieldState;
I'm currently building an app that uses compose TextFieldState and now I'm facing this error whenever im running the app:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/compose/foundation/text2/input/TextFieldState;
    at com.example.auth.presentation.login.phoneNumber.LoginState.<init>(LoginState.kt:9)
    at com.example.auth.presentation.login.phoneNumber.LoginViewModel.<init>(LoginViewModel.kt:27)
    at com.example.auth.presentation.di.AuthViewModelModuleKt$authViewModelModule$1$invoke$$inlined$viewModelOf$default$1.invoke(ViewModelOf.kt:231)
    at com.example.auth.presentation.di.AuthViewModelModuleKt$authViewModelModule$1$invoke$$inlined$viewModelOf$default$1.invoke(ViewModelOf.kt:63)
    at org.koin.core.instance.InstanceFactory.create(InstanceFactory.kt:50)
    at org.koin.core.instance.FactoryInstanceFactory.get(FactoryInstanceFactory.kt:38)
    at org.koin.core.registry.InstanceRegistry.resolveInstance$koin_core(InstanceRegistry.kt:109)
    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveValue(Scope.kt:247)
    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.resolveInstance(Scope.kt:233)
    at org.koin.core.scope.Scope.get(Scope.kt:212)
    at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.factory.KoinViewModelFactory.create(KoinViewModelFactory.kt:25)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$Factory.create(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:158)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl_androidKt.createViewModel(ViewModelProviderImpl.android.kt:34)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:65)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ViewModelProviderImpl.getViewModel$lifecycle_viewmodel_release$default(ViewModelProviderImpl.kt:47)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:91)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.android.kt:109)
    at org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.GetViewModelKt.resolveViewModel(GetViewModel.kt:43)
    at com.example.auth.presentation.login.phoneNumber.LoginScreenKt.LoginScreenRoot(LoginScreen.kt:162)
    at com.example.samanins.NavigationRootKt$authGraph$1$1.invoke(NavigationRoot.kt:33)
    at com.example.samanins.NavigationRootKt$authGraph$1$1.invoke(NavigationRoot.kt:32)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:308)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:401)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:85)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:380)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:295)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)

And I've heard that it maybe a version mismatch so this is my version catalog:
[versions]
agp = "8.5.2"
androidTools = "31.2.2"
core = "1.10.3"

#noinspection RiskyLibrary
playCore = "1.10.3"
coreSplashscreen = "1.0.1"
coilCompose = "2.6.0"
composeCompiler = "1.5.9"
desugar_jdk_libs = "2.0.4"
kotlin = "1.9.22"
coreKtx = "1.12.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.1.5"
espressoCore = "3.5.1"
activityCompose = "1.8.2"
ktor = "2.3.8"
ktorClientLogging = "2.3.8"
ktorServerCallLogging = "2.3.7"
koin = "3.5.3"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.7.0"
composeBom = "2024.05.00" #"2024.02.02"
materialIconsExtended = "1.6.3"
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"
securityCryptoKtx = "1.1.0-alpha06"
timber = "5.0.1"
ksp = "1.9.22-1.0.17"
room = "2.6.1"
appcompat = "1.6.1"
material = "1.11.0"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm = "1.9.22"
maps = "4.3.3"
coroutines = "1.8.0"
gmsLocation = "21.2.0"
mapsUtils = "5.0.0"
bson = "4.11.1"
work = "2.9.0"
kotlinx-serialization = "1.6.3"
secretsPlugin = "2.0.1"
playServicesMaps = "18.2.0"
annotation = "1.7.1"
material3Android = "1.3.0"

# Project versions
projectApplicationId = "com.plcoding.samanins"
projectVersionName = "1.0"
projectMinSdkVersion = "26"
projectTargetSdkVersion = "34"
projectCompileSdkVersion = "34"
projectVersionCode = "1"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-core-splashscreen = { module = "androidx.core:core-splashscreen", version.ref = "coreSplashscreen" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-compose = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-compose = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-material-icons-extended = { module = "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended", version.ref = "materialIconsExtended" }
androidx-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose", version.ref = "navigationCompose" }
androidx-security-crypto-ktx = { module = "androidx.security:security-crypto-ktx", version.ref = "securityCryptoKtx" }
coil-compose = { module = "io.coil-kt:coil-compose", version.ref = "coilCompose" }
core = { module = "com.google.android.play:core", version.ref = "playCore" }
core-testing = { module = "com.google.android.play:core-testing", version.ref = "playCore" }
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "kotlinx-serialization"}
kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "coroutines"}
kotlinx-coroutines-play-services = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services", version.ref = "coroutines"}
desugar-jdk-libs = { module = "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs", version.ref = "desugar_jdk_libs" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-work = { group = "androidx.work", name = "work-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "work" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-activity-compose = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-compose", version.ref = "activityCompose" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-compose-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-compose-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-compose-ui-tooling = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling" }
androidx-compose-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
androidx-compose-ui-tooling-preview = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-tooling-preview" }
androidx-compose-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-compose-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
koin-android-workmanager = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-workmanager", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-android = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-android", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-core = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-core", version.ref = "koin" }
koin-androidx-compose = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-compose", version.ref = "koin" }
ktor-client-auth = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-auth", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-cio = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-content-negotiation = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-logging = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging", version.ref = "ktorClientLogging" }
ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-server-call-logging = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-server-call-logging", version.ref = "ktorServerCallLogging" }
room-compiler = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-compiler", version.ref = "room" }
room-ktx = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-ktx", version.ref = "room" }
room-runtime = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-runtime", version.ref = "room" }
timber = { module = "com.jakewharton.timber:timber", version.ref = "timber" }
appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
google-maps-android-compose = { module = "com.google.maps.android:maps-compose", version.ref = "maps" }
google-android-gms-play-services-location = { module = "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location", version.ref = "gmsLocation"}
org-mongodb-bson = { module = "org.mongodb:bson", version.ref = "bson" }
play-services-maps = { group = "com.google.android.gms", name = "play-services-maps", version.ref = "playServicesMaps" }
google-maps-android-utils-ktx = { module = "com.google.maps.android:maps-utils-ktx", version.ref = "mapsUtils"}
annotation = { group = "androidx.annotation", name = "annotation", version.ref = "annotation" }
androidx-material3-android = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3-android", version.ref = "material3Android" }

# Gradle
android-gradlePlugin = { group = "com.android.tools.build", name = "gradle", version.ref = "agp" }
android-tools-common = { group = "com.android.tools", name = "common", version.ref = "androidTools" }
kotlin-gradlePlugin = { group = "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name = "kotlin-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "kotlin" }
ksp-gradlePlugin = { group = "com.google.devtools.ksp", name = "com.google.devtools.ksp.gradle.plugin", version.ref = "ksp" }
room-gradlePlugin = { group = "androidx.room", name = "room-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "room" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
android-library = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
kotlin-serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }
room = { id = "androidx.room", version.ref = "room" }
jetbrains-kotlin-jvm = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm", version.ref = "org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm" }
androidDynamicFeature = { id = "com.android.dynamic-feature", version.ref = "agp" }
mapsplatform-secrets-plugin = { id = "com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin", version.ref = "secretsPlugin"}

samanins-android-application = { id = "samanins.android.application", version = "unspecified" }
samanins-android-application-compose = { id = "samanins.android.application.compose", version = "unspecified" }
samanins-android-library = { id = "samanins.android.library", version = "unspecified" }
samanins-android-library-compose = { id = "samanins.android.library.compose", version = "unspecified" }
samanins-android-feature-ui = { id = "samanins.android.feature.ui", version = "unspecified" }
samanins-android-room = { id = "samanins.android.room", version = "unspecified" }
samanins-jvm-library = { id = "samanins.jvm.library", version = "unspecified" }
samanins-jvm-ktor = { id = "samanins.jvm.ktor", version = "unspecified" }

The versions that you see have a different version commented infront of them mean that they were tried too.

From the documentation of TextFieldState:

Added in 1.7.0

You use the Compose BOM 2024.05.00 which uses the Compose foundation library in version 1.6.7.
From the official BOM Mapping, the first BOM using 1.7.0 is 2024.09.00. Updating the version accordingly should fix that.
Please also note that during development this class changed packages, so make sure you use the correct import statement:
import androidx.compose.foundation.text.input.TextFieldState


thanks that indeed was the answer
but i have a couple of questions

how can i figure out what version of composeFoundation is a particular BOM using ?
how do i know that the version is causing my error ?
after i figured out that my problem is a version mismatch is there a general rule or way of finding out the right version ?
since we lack textAsFlow extension function in composeFoundation 1.7.0 what is best practice to observe text changes ?

feel free to answer to any of the questions or maybe all of them if you feel like it sir !! :)

I added a link to the BOM mapping. Regarding 2. and 3.: From the error message it was clear that TextFieldState was missing. I knew from experience that that was a recent addition, but simply googling for the class would lead to the first link in my answer, revealing that you need the Compose Foundation library in at least version 1.7.0 for it. Using the BOM mapping you can then check if your current BOM supports that - which it didn't. Pretty straightforward when you know how everything is interconnected, something you'll just learn over time when working with it.

Regarding textAsFlow: That was removed in the final version, I guess it didn't warrant a dedicated function because it was a simple call to snapshotFlow which converts a Compose State into a Flow. If you want it back, use this: fun TextFieldState.textAsFlow() = snapshotFlow { text }

I ran into the same issue with TextFieldState and managed to resolve it by downgrading navigationCompose from:
navigationCompose = "2.8.3"

to:
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"

However, I see you’re already using 2.7.7, so that might not be the solution here.
I’ll share my library versions below—try matching them to yours to see if it helps resolve the issue. Let me know if it works!
[versions]
agp = "8.2.2"
androidTools = "31.5.0"
core = "1.10.3"
featureDelivery = "2.1.0"
coreSplashscreen = "1.0.1"
coilCompose = "2.6.0"
composeCompiler = "1.5.9"
desugar_jdk_libs = "2.1.2"
kotlin = "1.9.22"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
activityCompose = "1.9.3"
ktor = "2.3.12"
ktorClientLogging = "2.3.12"
ktorServerCallLogging = "2.3.7"
koin = "3.5.6"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.8.6"
composeBom = "2024.06.00"
materialIconsExtended = "1.7.4"
navigationCompose = "2.7.7"
securityCryptoKtx = "1.1.0-alpha06"
timber = "5.0.1"
ksp = "1.9.22-1.0.17"
room = "2.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
material = "1.11.0"
org-jetbrains-kotlin-jvm = "1.9.22"
maps = "4.3.3"
coroutines = "1.8.0"
gmsLocation = "21.3.0"
mapsUtils = "5.0.0"
bson = "4.11.1"
work = "2.9.1"
kotlinx-serialization = "1.6.3"
secretsPlugin = "2.0.1"
playServicesMaps = "19.0.0"
annotation = "1.9.0"


Please make sure your answer actually answers the question. As it is right now it seems more like guesswork. Please [edit] your answer to be more assertive and based in fact. That said, this question already has an accepted answer. If you do not have something substantially new to contribute you probably shouldn't even write another answer at all.
